# How to create a BIG HEAD in longtable

Tags: longtable, multicolumn

Good night,
I'm with a wheezy looking to create a 'pdf' with 'pdflatex' for sending by email with 'mutt'.
The result of filtering the output of the 'runrepport' is saved in a 'tex' is processed later.

The code used is as follows:

**% LATEX con logtable

```
\documentclass[a4paper] {article}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.5}

\usepackage[left=0.5cm,top=1cm,right=0.5cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|l|c|c|c|}

\multicolumn{7}{|l|}{\Huge{EMPRESA}} \\

\multicolumn{7}{|l|}{\normalsize{Direccion EMPRESA}} \\

\multicolumn{7}{|l|}{\normalsize{Poblacion EMPRESA}} \\

\multicolumn{7}{|l|}{\normalsize{Cod.Postal y Provincia EMPRESA}} \\

\multicolumn{7}{|l|}{\normalsize{NIF:}} \\

\hline 

\multicolumn{3}{|l}{\normalsize{FACTURA: 178.256}}  &

\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\normalsize{CLIENTE: CORDERO REUNIDOS S.L.}} \\

\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\normalsize{FECHA..: 12/09/2013}} &

\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\normalsize{DIRECCION CLIENTE }} \\

\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\normalsize{COD.CLIENTE:  10.000}} & 

\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\normalsize{COD.POSTAL y POBLACION }} \\

\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\normalsize{NIF.CLIENTE: A08220220 }} & 

\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\normalsize{PROVINCIA }} \\

\hline 

\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{{FECHA}} & 

\multicolumn{1}{c|}{{ALBARAN}} & 

\multicolumn{1}{c|}{{ARTICULO}} & 

\multicolumn{1}{l|}{{DESCRIPCION}} & 

\multicolumn{1}{c|}{{CANTIDAD}} & 

\multicolumn{1}{c|}{{PRECIO}} &

\multicolumn{1}{c|}{{IMPORTE}} \\ 

\hline 

\endhead

14.10.13 & 145.248 & 45878  & REF: Tuercas 20x12 & 16 & 1.23 & 23.23\\

14.10.13 & 145.248 & 45878  & REF: Tuercas 20x12 & 16 & 1.23 & 23.23\\

14.10.13 & 145.248 & 45238  & REF: Arandelas 12x13 & 23 & 1.23 & 21.34\\

14.10.13 & 145.248 & 45238  & ======= ULTIMA LINEA ===== & 23 & 1.23 & 21.34\\

% ======================== 150 lines more =================================

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

**

The output is good, but I would like to put the group "CLIENTE - DIRECCION - COD.POSTAL - PROVICIA" right in the middle of "DESCRIPCION" to be more aesthetic.

Is that possible?
thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's not really clear what you mean by "right in the middle".

Answer (score 4):

It's not too clear what layout you want, but perhaps something like this

[image]

Note:

- if using `|` in multicolumn *only* use it on the right of an entry, except in the first column,

  - Size change commands work like `\huge xx` not `\huge{xx}` and there is no need to explicitly switch to `\normalsize`
  - You can use `\extrarowheight` from the array package to better separate the horizontal rules.

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper] {article}

%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.5}% No!

\usepackage[left=0.5cm,top=1cm,right=0.5cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable,array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|l|c|c|c|}
\multicolumn{7}{|l|}{\Huge EMPRESA} \\
\multicolumn{7}{|l|}{Direccion EMPRESA} \\
\multicolumn{7}{|l|}{Poblacion EMPRESA} \\
\multicolumn{7}{|l|}{Cod.Postal y Provincia EMPRESA} \\
\multicolumn{7}{|l|}{NIF:} \\
\hline 
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{
\begin{tabular}{l}
FACTURA: 178.256\\
FECHA..: 12/09/2013\\
COD.CLIENTE:  10.000\\
NIF.CLIENTE: A08220220
\end{tabular}}
&
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{
\begin{tabular}{l}
CLIENTE: CORDERO REUNIDOS S.L. \\
DIRECCION CLIENTE \\
COD.POSTAL y POBLACION  \\
PROVINCIA
\end{tabular}}
\\
\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{FECHA} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{ALBARAN} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{ARTICULO} & 
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{DESCRIPCION} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{CANTIDAD} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{PRECIO} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{IMPORTE} \\ 
\hline 
\endhead
14.10.13 & 145.248 & 45878  & REF: Tuercas 20x12 & 16 & 1.23 & 23.23\\
14.10.13 & 145.248 & 45878  & REF: Tuercas 20x12 & 16 & 1.23 & 23.23\\
14.10.13 & 145.248 & 45238  & REF: Arandelas 12x13 & 23 & 1.23 & 21.34\\
14.10.13 & 145.248 & 45238  & ======= ULTIMA LINEA ===== & 23 & 1.23 & 21.34\\
%======================== 150 lines more =================================
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is a very good option, THANK YOU!  +1